# What does a constructor return?

Tags: c++, constructor, return-type

My question is what does a constructor return? This question is not quite different from "What is the return type of a constructor?"
I have read somewhere that a constructor returns a complete object **implicitly** (i.e implicit return type is the name of the class) but it shall not be specified explicitly.

```
struct empty{};

int main(){
   empty(); //creates a temporary and implicitly a constructor is called
}
```

So as per my interpretation the implicit return type should be the name of the class, in this case `empty`. Is my *wild* interpretation correct?

Comment: Well, when you call `new Class();`, it returns a pointer to the location of that instance of the class. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598833/how-does-it-work-test-pobj-new-test-as-constructor-does-not-return-anythin

Comment: Removed from the `c++-faq` tag. Please [discuss](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/212892#212892) if you disagree.

Answer (score 35):

A constructor doesn't return anything.  A constructor is called to initialize an object.  A constructor can only be used to initialize an object; you can't actually call a constructor explicitly (for one thing, constructors do not have names).

In the example you give, `empty()` is not a function call expression, it is value initialization.  It creates a value-initialized temporary object of type `empty`.

Comment: See Alf P. Steinbach's post here :http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t281999-newbie-question-constructor-return-type.html. He said `A constructor does not have a return type, and yes it is _in a sense_ the object itself, which the constructor constructs`.

Comment: I was referring to the last part of his statement.

Comment: @Invisible:  The important part of that statement is "in a sense:"  that's not exactly what happens and it's not strictly correct, but it's a good way of thinking about constructors and initialization.

Comment: Adding to "you can't actually call a constructor" - sometimes, there's a reason to want to construct an object in memory that has already been allocated. The idea of an explicit call to a constructor may be compelling - but in fact even that doesn't work. The "placement new" syntax is used instead. Though in a slight asymmetry, the cleanup action that complements this (destruct the object but don't free the memory) is an explicit destructor call - not a "placement delete".

Comment: An extra thought - within the constructor (as with any method) the object is referenced via the `this` implicit parameter. The pointer to the instance (or rather uninitialised memory) is passed in, not returned out. Though of course the references via `this` are usually as implicit as the parameter itself.

Comment: You could also mention that there is no such thing as a pointer to constructor (as opposed to a pointer to member function, which *does* exist).

Comment: @James, you *could* call a constructor explicitly by saying `empty::empty()`. That's disallowed, but the name `empty::empty` in there refers to the constructor (by translating the injected class name from a reference to a type to a reference to the constructor - that's a special twist in the spec).

Comment: What about [Terminator().say();](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea20f96174cec700). Looks like reference to created object to me. Sort of...

Comment: @doc: Yes. It constructs a temporary Terminator object, calls Terminator::say() on that temporary object, then destroys that temporary object.  Temporary objects are not destroyed until the end of the full expression in which they were constructed.

Comment: Or unless you use a const reference to prolong a lifetime of temporary object. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a3672ea05d2a10d

Comment: So, could we say that constructor returns nothing, but it has return by value semantics? :P I imagine if return type was specified a signature would look like `Terminator Terminator::Terminator()` rather than `void Terminator::Terminator()`.

Answer (score 11):

construct does return something.  it returns reference to object that `this` points to.  so the implicit return statement from a constructor looks like

```
*this;
```

How is this used?

If you create a class template of `something` with a "generic" type as member, you call the default zero parameter constructor of the generic type explicitly (i.e., `generic()` ) in the constructor of your class `something` and initialize your generic member via the assignment operator and initialization statement of the `something` constructor.  Constructor has to return something or none of that crap I just wrote would work.  It's in the book I'm reading...lol.

Answer (score 3):

Constructors do not return anything.
Constructors are called implicitly while object creation to initialize the object being created.

Comment: Then, how can this statement be legit?: `MyClass myclass = MyClass();`

Comment: @hkBattousai There are bunch of special rules handling initializers. Unfortunately it has nothing to do with how to get something looking like being returned from a constructor. Since a constructor even does not have a name (the class name here is handled by special rules of declarator rather than function call's _postfix-expression_), you have no way to refer to its type so the "return type" (if any) does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

> A constructor doesn't return anything.

**Source of confusion:**

```
Book *b = new Book();
```

Many are confused by the above code, which creates an *illusion that the constructor returns a pointer to the newly created object*.

When you use `new` keyword, the compiler allocates required memory and then calls the constructor to create a new object on the allocated memory. Then `new` returns the pointer to that memory block. The constructor only creates the object and never returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if I remember correctly, your code will allocate enough room for an "empty" on the stack, and then call empty's default constructor--as specified by the ()--implicitly passing it a this reference.  There is no return.  And in your case there is no constructor.

Comment: All classes/structs have constructors. In this case, there's the "default default constructor" - the do-nothing default constructor that every type gets unless you say otherwise. IIRC, in C++0x it will be a fill-with-zeros implicit default constructor instead.

Comment: As other poster, `new` allocates the memory, not the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

what about this:

```
int main() {
const empty &er = empty();
empty *ep = const_cast<empty*>(er); //casting away conentness to make changes in the members
cout<<"\n main ends \n";
//dtor get called here
}
```

ctor returns a const reference to a memory location(*this), you can cast away the const and use its as a nonconst normal object like `empty *e = new e;`

Comment: Good point, but const references [prolong lifetime of temporaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685460/do-non-const-references-prolong-the-lives-of-temporaries). Thus ctor behaves like it's returning by value. If it returned const reference you could just `empty & er = const_cast<empty &>(empty())`.