# Do *non*-const references prolong the lives of temporaries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, language-lawyer

Once upon a time, I assumed that code like this would fail:

```
const MyClass& obj = MyClass();
obj.DoSomething();
```

because the MyClass object would be destroyed at the end of its full-expression, leaving obj as a dangling reference. However, I learned (here) that this isn't true; the standard actually has a special provision that allows const references to keep temporaries alive until said references are destroyed themselves. But, it was emphasized, only *const* references have this power. Today I ran the code below in VS2012 as an experiment.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }
};

void f()
{
    Foo& f = Foo();
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

The output when calling `f()` was:

```
ctor  
Hello world  
dtor
```

So I had a look at the C++11 draft standard, and only found this (§ 12.2/4):

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a
>   different point than the end of the full-expression. The first context [doesn't
>   apply]. The second context is when a reference is bound to a
>   temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the
>   temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the
>   reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference.

The word `const` is conspicuously absent from the above. So; has this behavior been changed for C++11, was I wrong about the `const` thing to begin with, or does VS2012 have a bug and I just haven't found the relevant part of the standard?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The behavior hasn't changed, you just need to turn your warning level up to `/W4`. VisualStudio implements the lifetime extension rule even for non-`const` lvalue references as a compiler extension. In this context, binding an rvalue to the non-`const` reference behaves the same as if you were binding it to a `const` reference.

With `/W4` you'd see this:

```
warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'Foo' to 'Foo &'
1>  A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
```

The text disallowing binding of an rvalue to a non-`const` lvalue reference can be found in *§8.5.3/5*

> — Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile `const` type (i.e., *cv1* shall be
>   `const`), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.
> [ Example:
>
> ```
>   double& rd2 = 2.0; // error: not an lvalue and reference not const
>   int i = 2;
>   double& rd3 = i; // error: type mismatch and reference not const
> ```
>
> —end example ]

The second half of the quoted statement is what allows binding of a temporary to an rvalue reference, as shown in [litb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23685690/241631).

```
string &&s = string("hello");
```

This, combined with the lifetime extension rule in *§12.2/5*, means the lifetime of the temporary will now match the lifetime of the (rvalue) reference it is bound to.

Comment: The fact that you're allowed to bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference is itself an extension.

Comment: @Brian Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @Praetorian Indeed I do. So the "only const references extend lifetime" rule is a side-effect of some other rule stating that only const references can be bound to rvalues?

Comment: @dlf Finally found the text you were looking for, see updated answer

Comment: @Praetorian Great; I had been hunting too without success. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @dlf There's never been a rule that "only const references extend lifetime".  Long before the rule banning initialization of a non-const reference with a temporary, the extension of the lifetime applied to all references.

Comment: Given that this is a C++11 question, a mention of rvalue reference lifetime extension (for a standards-compliant non-`const` reference extension) might be a good idea.

Comment: @Yakk The quote does contain *or the reference shall be an rvalue reference*. Anyway, I've made it more explicit.

Answer (score 13):

The word `const` was never present in this section.  The rule
has always been (from as long as I can remember) that
a temporary used to initialize a reference has its lifetime
extended to match that of the reference, regardless of the type
of the reference.

Sometime in the late 1980's (very pre-standard), C++ introduced
the rule that a temporary could not be used to initialize
a non-const reference.  Initializing a non-const reference with
a temporary would still extend the lifetime (presumably), but
since you couldn't do it...  Most compilers implemented
a transition period, in which such an initialization would only
emit a warning (and the lifetime was extended).

For some reason, when Microsoft finally decided to implement
C++ (some time in the early 1990's), they decided not to
implement the new rule, and allowed initialization of
a non-const reference with a temporary (without even a warning,
at a time when most other vendors were gradually turning the
warning into an error).  And of course, the implemented the
usual lifetime rule.

Finally, in C++11, new types of references were introduced,
which allowed (or even required) initialization with
a temporary.  The rule about the lifetime of temporaries hasn't
changed, though; a temporary which is used to initialize
a reference (regardless of the type of reference) has its
lifetime extended.

(With a few exceptions: I would not recommend using a temporary
to initialize a class member reference in an initialization
list.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on that last paragraph regarding member references? It never occurred to me to do this, anyway, but I'd be interested in your exact reasoning.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The lifetime of a temporary used to initialize a member reference is _not_ extended to the lifetime of the reference; its lifetime ends at the end of the constructor (which results in a dangling reference).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would have guessed so intuitively, but it's nice to have it confirmed. Still makes me wonder why such a thing does not require a compiler diagnostic in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

No, because rvalue references don't need to be `const`, so the Standard quote is correct

```
string &&s = string("hello");
```

The lifetime is still enlargened. The constraints that make the code invalid for non-const lvalue reference is at clause 8 (notice that it is not the right place to just add "const" and "rvalue reference" etc in the paragraph you quoted. You need an *active rejection* of such bindings, not just saying that the lifetime of such bindings are not enlarged because you would leave the binding itself still wellformed).

Comment: The question really asks *three* yes-no questions chained together. It's unclear to me which one you're answering *no* to. Or are you giving the same answer to all three?