# When using std::forward, why am I able to call an l-value reference function while passing in an r-value?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, reference, perfect-forwarding

I'm going through r-value references and move semantics, currently, and I'm seeing an odd discrepancy in my own coding experimentation.

Given the below code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X{};

void g(X&& t) // A
{
    cout << "Rref call" << endl;
}    

void g(X& t) // B
{
    cout << "Lref call" << endl;
}    

template<typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    g(forward<T>(t));
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    f(x);   // 1
    f(X()); // 2

    return 0;
}
```

Will generate the expected output here:

> Lref call
>
> Rref call

However, if I go ahead and delete the overloaded function g that takes an r-value reference (denoted above on comment line // A), I get the following output:

> Lref call
>
> Lref call

How does this work out? Why doesn't the compiler complain about a call to `g(X& t)` while trying to pass in a `X&&`?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, it has a [non-standard extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object) to allow temporaries to bind to non-const references. It fails [in this example](http://ideone.com/TcJbJA).

Comment: James, that looks to be exactly it. Was going nuts trying to figure out the logic happening. Much obliged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you comment out the `g(X&& t)` overload, you're using an [MSVC extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23685580/241631) that allows binding rvalues to non-`const` lvalue references. If you turn up the warning level to `/W4`, MSVC will tell you a non-standard extension is being used.

Both gcc and clang [fail to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e70e789c9551181) the code with that overload commented out.

Comment: Yup! Was using Visual Studio and it was happily accepting this. Thanks kindly.

Comment: This is one of the most terrible bugs in MSVC. And while it might had some sense back in the days when there were no rvalue references, it has 0 sense now. They should've turned it off for C++11 code.

Comment: @SergeyA Well it is turned off if you compile with `/W4` and `/WX`, as you should be :) But I don't want to make excuses for them, this is a terrible extension.