# Lifetime extension of temporary by non-const reference using const-cast

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, object-lifetime, const-cast

This is something that came up recently and which I feel shouldn't work as it apparently does:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int>& ptr = const_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>&>(
        static_cast<const std::shared_ptr<int>&>(
            std::shared_ptr<int>(
                new int(5), [](int* p) {std::cout << "Deleting!"; *p = 999;  delete(p); }
            )
        )
    );
    std::cout << "I'm using a non-const ref to a temp! " << *ptr << " ";
}
```

The use of `shared_ptr` isn't necessary here, but the custom deleter allows for an easy demonstration of the lifetime of the resulting object. There resulting output from Visual Studio, Clang and GCC is the same:

> I'm using a non-const ref to a temp! 5 Deleting!

Meaning the lifetime of the resulting `shared_ptr` has, through some mechanism, been extended to match that of the `std::shared_ptr<int>& ptr`.

### What's Happening?

Now, I'm aware that the lifetime of a temporary will be extended to that of the reference for the case of a constant reference. But the only named object is a non-const reference, all other intermediate representations I would expect to have a lifetime equal only to the initialization expression.

Additionally, Microsoft have an extension which allows non-const references to extend the lifetime of a bound temporary, but this behaviour appears to be present even when that extension is disabled and, additionally, also appears in Clang and GCC.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8246688/11480329) I believe the temporary is implicitly being created as `const`, so attempting to modify the object referenced by `ptr` is probably undefined behaviour, but I'm not sure that knowledge tells me anything about why the lifetime is being extended. My understanding is that it is the act of *modifying* a const that is UB, not simply taking a non-const reference to it.

My understanding of what should be happening is as follows:

1. `Type()` creates a prvalue with no cv-specification.
2. `static_cast<const Type&>(...)` materializes that prvalue into a const xvalue with a lifetime equal to the interior expression. We then create a const lvalue reference to that const xvalue. The lifetime of the xvalue is extended to match that of the const lvalue reference.
3. `const_cast<Type&>(...)` produces an lvalue reference which is then assigned to `ptr`. *The const lvalue reference then expires, taking the materialized xvalue with it.*
4. *I try to read dangling reference `ptr` and bad things happen.*

What's wrong in my understanding? Why don't the bits in italics happen?

As an extra bonus question, am I correct in thinking that the underlying object is const, and that any attempt to modify it through this path will result in undefined behaviour?

Comment: if your understanding is correct, then there is UB and the output is just a symptom of UB. Out of all the "bad things" the worst is "appears to work as expected". Anyhow, I hope there can be an answer that does not need the x/p/r-mumbo-jumbo ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I ran the code using UB Sanitizer (also Address Sanitizer) and it did not complain.  That doesn't mean there's no UB, but nothing jumps out.

Comment: @JohnZwinck actually I cannot follow OPs reasoning completely, I dont think there is anything `const` here, but I really have no idea what is actually going on

Comment: _What's wrong in my understanding?_ You believe that cast operators somehow "produce" references as if references were objects which are created or destroyed.

Comment: See http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6. Lifetime extension in your code is the correct behavior, because the initializer of the reference is `const_cast` (6.6.1) applied to `static_cast` (6.6.2) which triggered temporary materialization (6.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reference can extend the lifetime of an object.  However, a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary as in your example.  The Microsoft extension you refer to is not "Extend lifetime by non-const references," rather "Let non-const references bind to temporaries."  They have that extension for backward compatibility with their own previous broken compiler versions.

By a cast you have forced the binding of a non-const reference to a temporary, which does not appear to be invalid, just unusual because it cannot be done directly.  Once you've accomplished that binding, lifetime extension occurs for your non-const reference the same as it would for a const reference.

More information: [Do *non*-const references prolong the lives of temporaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685460/do-non-const-references-prolong-the-lives-of-temporaries)

Comment: Interesting. So the Microsoft extension is to allow binding of temporaries to non-const references only, rather than changing how lifetime extension itself works. What about the const-ness of the underlying object, is my assumption that it is effectively const correct?

Comment: Your object is not const.  You can call `ptr.reset(...)` for example.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The object materialized by `static_cast<const std::shared_ptr<int>&>` **is** const.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: You have lived up to your name.  Yes, the object materialized by the cast you mention is const.  But what I would call the "underlying object" (the shared_ptr itself, rather than the reference) is not const, nor is its outermost reference.

Comment: @JohnZwinck You mean that on a common implementation this object is created in a "writeable" storage so you may modify it as if the object wasn't const.

Answer (score 0):

The linked article is plainly wrong. A temporary is not (necessarily) a const object. The fact that it cannot bind to a non-const refetence is of no importance. It can bind to a rvalue reference with no need for a cast, and be modified through such reference. There is no UB in doing that. One can also call non-const member functions on a temporary. The entire concept of move semantics is based on this fact.

Binding to a normal non-const reference and modifying through it is a different way to accompish the same thing. It requires a cast but otherwise it is very similar to the above.